# Is it possible to open outlook or word(MS Word) in client machine from a web application in MVC5

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

We are developing a web application in MVC5,Our client is required to open the document in word(MS Word) from the web application and send mail through the outlook also,Is it possible to do. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your client can download the document and it should open in Word, but a web app simply cannot open applications on the client PC. A desktop app could do all this, though.

Comment: No, that would be a big security risk (you don't want any website starting a random application on the users pc)

Comment: "Our client is required to open the document in word(MS Word) from the web application and send mail through the outlook" ...why don't you just send the email on their behalf and save them this manual task?

Answer (score 3):

Your site can't force the client to open whatever app you want them to use for security reasons.

To send an email you can create an email link, do note that it'll open outlook or whatever the default email app is on the client

```
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com">Send mail</a>
```

You could also follow the @ADyson suggestion and send the email on their behalf on the server side.

To open as word, you have to provide a download link for the file and when the user downloads the file he can click on the downloaded file to open as word. This implies the file is recognized by word and the user have word installed.

Comment: "To open as word the browser will look up the extension of the file you're downloading and open the accordingly app." ...not usually, no. Usually it will just download the file. The browser is not allowed to start any application on your machine unless it is associated with a recognised protocol (such as mailto or tel). Word docs are generally not assigned any such protocol. **If** the browser has a plugin installed which understands the Word format then it might try to open the file inline in a browser window using that plugin, but it totally depends on the local configuration.

Comment: Once the download is finished if you click on it via browser the word app is executed. If you have word installed.

Comment: Yes that's entirely true. But that isn't what you said in the answer - you stated that the browser will do this automatically. It won't, you have to click on it. And the fact it then knows what application to use to open the file is a feature of the operating system, not the browser.

Comment: That's better. So the missing part of your post now is to actually answer the user's question (i.e. "no, it's not possible to do any of this automatically, you have to do it manually" (because although you can launch an email by getting the user to click on the mailto link, which is sort of semi-automatic, it still won't attach the file or send the message without further clicking). P.S. Points will also be given for incorporating my suggestion (see comments above) that the application should maybe handle all of this on the server-side... :-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  If they have Outlook installed and registered as the default e-mail app on Windows, then it'll open Outlook, otherwise there's no way to force Outlook to open.

For Word, if you return the [correct mime-type](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/) from your web service (e.g. for .docx it's `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`), and if they have Word installed and registered to handle .docx files, then yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

[This is my outlook window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jamYz.png)

```
 <a href="mailto:one@gmail.com?subject=See the attachment&cc=anotherdude@gmail.com,thirddude&attachment='C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Notes\\SQL Query.txt'">Send mail</a>
```

In our above code instead of attachment all are working properly. How can be attach document with this code